# Implementing a simple tac program

Tags: perl

I was trying to solve an exercise in "Learning Perl" by Schwartz, when I happened across an unexpected output in the code I wrote. I was wondering what I've done wrong.

Qn: Implement a simple tac similiar to the unix utility.

My solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;
while (<>) {
    push @array, $_;
}

foreach ($#array..0) {
    print $array[$_];
}
```

Implementing it with: `$ ./tac list`

where list contains:

```
$ cat list 
An apple 
Blue boys
Coy cows
Dreary ducks!
```

gives no output.

```
$ ./tac list
$
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I've added a couple more examples to it that you may like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the `foreach` loop counter. You can't go backwards like that.

You could instead do:

```
while (@array) {
    print pop @array;
}
```

or just:

```
print pop @array while (@array);
```

`while (@array)` will evaluate `@array` in a *scalar context*, which means that the size of the array will be tested. When the size reaches zero, the loop will terminate.

---

As this is perl, there are of course a million ways to do this. Another would be:

```
print for reverse @array
```

...or you could read in the array backwards by using `unshift`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;
while (<>) {
    unshift @array, $_;
}

print for @array;
```

...or you could even just do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print reverse <>;
```

Enjoy learning Perl!

Comment: @TLP thanks for the edit. I'm not sure why I used `map` there, especially since I did `print for @array` in the next example.

Comment: `print reverse <>` is a great one-liner for command lines that don't have `tac` in the path.

Answer (score 2):

The range notation doesn't count down:

```
$ perl -e 'foreach my $i (10..0) { print "$i\n"; }'
$
```

You can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = <>;

foreach (0..$#array)
{
    print $array[$#array - $_];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't countdown in `foreach` loop. You can use `reverse` to achieve the same task

```
my @array = <>;

foreach (reverse 0..$#array)
{
    print $array[$_];
}
```